# Using keyword with virtual inheritance in cpp

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual, using

I want to resolve an inheritance problem of my Paladin class. Here is a resume of the inheritance between my classes :

```cpp
class Peasant
{
    virtual int attack();
}

class Knight : virtual public Peasant
{
    int attack() override;
}

class Enchanter : public Peasant
{
    int attack() override;
}

class Priest : virtual public Enchanter

class Paladin : public Knight, public Priest
{
    using Knight::attack();
}
```

This way I got the following error :

```
Paladin.hpp:16:7: error: no unique final redefinition « virtual int Peasant::attack() » in « Paladin »
   16 | class Paladin : public Knight, public Priest
      |       ^~~~~~~
```

*Words may differ in the official error message as I traduce this error from another language to english.*

I solved my problem this way :

```cpp
class Peasant
{
    int attack();
}

class Knight : virtual public Peasant
{
    int attack();
}

class Enchanter : public Peasant
{
    int attack();
}

class Priest : virtual public Enchanter

class Paladin : public Knight, public Priest
{
    using Knight::attack();
}
```

But I don't really like this solution. I prefer using `virtual` and `override` when I override the base's methods in derived classes.
I know I could do :

```cpp
class Peasant
{
    virtual int attack();
}

class Knight : virtual public Peasant
{
    virtual int attack() override;
}

class Enchanter : public Peasant
{
    virtual int attack() override;
}

class Priest : virtual public Enchanter

class Paladin : public Knight, public Priest
{
    int attack() override {return Knight::attack();};
}
```

But in the case I'm just re-using a method, I think it's more elegant to use `using`.

**So I would like to know if there is a way to use both `virtual`/`override` and `using` in the same syntax.**

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: What would be the purpose of adding an `override` to a `using`? The `using` does not override anything

Comment: And it makes no sense to inherit the same class both virtually and on-virtually. The result is utter confusion. Perhaps rethink the relationship between the various classes in this hierarchy?

Comment: Also none of the examples actually compile due to various syntax and access specifier errors, making it very hard to tell what your original problem was

Comment: "Knights and priests are special kinds of peasants". Really?

Comment: Rule of thumb: virtual inheritance everywhere or nowhere. in `Enchanter`, `Peasant` should be a virtual base.

Comment: `class Enchanter : public Peasant` as stated by Pete, you are missing `virtual` here.

Comment: "I solved my problem this way :...." its not just your personal preference, but overriding a method does require the method to be virtual. You cannot override a non virtual method and in that middle code nothing is being overridden

Comment: You may consider `using` more elegant, but it just doesn't work the way you want. You must override the function. There are no other options here.

Answer (score 2):

Your second option is the correct way to go. `using` doesn't define a function, it brings a name into scope.

You also have another error, `attack` is private in each of these classes, so you can't `return Knight::attack()`.

Not a syntax error, but you are missing `virtual` off your inheritance at least in `Enchanter`, and probably in `Paladin`.

```
struct Peasant
{
    virtual int attack();
};

struct Knight : virtual Peasant
{
    int attack() override;
};

struct Enchanter : virtual Peasant
{
    int attack() override;
};

struct Priest : virtual Enchanter
{};

struct Paladin : virtual Knight, virtual Priest
{
    int attack() override { return Knight::attack(); };
};
```

However, trying to embed the rules of a game into subclasses within an inheritance hierarchy [can be like fitting a round peg in a square hole](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/).